# Threshold error when trying to change URL of the Site

Tags: 2013, list-view-threshold

I have a weird problem. This happens on a sub site in a site collection and both sub site and site collection does not have any big lists that exceed the threshold. However when site collection administrator tries to change the site URL she gets :

*The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold enforced by the administrator.*

I can do it as a Farm administrator and in the ULS logs it says:

> Application error when access /_layouts/15/prjsetng.aspx, Error=The
>   attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view
>   threshold enforced by the administrator.    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.RenameWeb(String
>   bstrUrl, String bstrNewUrl)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.RenameWeb(String bstrUrl,
>   String bstrNewUrl)

As there are no big lists, I am really baffled why this is happening. Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes big lists can't be identified right away, for example when using workflows. If you are using workflows, check if the workflow history tasks list may exceed the threshold limit.

Alternative go to the Central Admin and navigate to your web applications. Select the web application where the problem occurs, open the dropdown of General Settings and choose Resource Throttling. Double the value of List View Threshold and check if the error still occurs.

Comment: I don't want to change the threshold value really. But I'll see if WF history list is big. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: You can ramp it up temporarily then back it off once the operation is complete. I had to rename a site with many sub-sites and it worked fine.